# Cambia de versión de Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Instale esta version de rails por error:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.2.1
```

Pero yo quiero tener la version 4.2.5.

Hay alguna forma en la que pueda cambiar de version de rails?

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tienes que definir en el archivo Gemfile de Bundler la versión que quieres usar. De esta forma, cuando ejecutes `bundle install` se instalará la gema Rails en la versión especificada.

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.5'
```

Saludos

Comment: En el ejemplo que describe el OP, se estaría haciendo un downgrade de 5.2.1 a 4.2.5, o sea de una major version, y varias cosas han cambiado entre major versions, entre ellas configuración, uso de gemas, etc. Creo que lo más sano es comenzar un proyecto desde cero si es un proyecto nuevo. Ahora si ya es un proyecto viejo, esta opción valdría la pena... aunque en general hay que analizar bien el por qué de hacer un downgrade, ya que la mayoría de las veces no tiene mayor sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.5
```

Y puedes iniciar un proyecto rails desde cero con la nueva versión

Answer (score 0):

Instala un gestor de versiones, como [RVM](https://rvm.io/)

ademas puedes tener instaladas varias versiones y 
asi puedes ir cambiando entre versiones:

ej: rvm use 4.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Al inicio utilizaba muchisimo RVM, pero luego conocí Rbenv, esta genial, las soluciones que te brindan para instalar otra versión de la gema Rails es correcta, pero en este punto creo que es mejor que tengas instalado un manejador de versiones de Ruby, aqui podrás tener instalado en tu computador, no solo ruby 2.5, sino tambien otras versiones ádemas de que cada version puede tener su lista de gemas propias.

Te recomiendo que le des un vistaso a ambas opciones, RVM o Rbenv(yo prefiero esta)

Answer (score -1):

Usar [rvm](https://rvm.io/) te funciona si lo que necesitas es correr proyectos de rails con diferentes versiones, no solo de Rails sino también de Ruby. Lo que menciona @edwin-vasques creo que sería tu mejor opción.

Tambien puedes usar **rails *5.0.0* new appname** para crear un proyecto con una versión específica de rails.